# Finding entries that are within 30 min of each other - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find if there are any entries that have the same ID and also are within 30 mins of each other and the ID is always arranged in numerical order

The ID is in column A, date and time in column B, in column C and D i have these respectively

```
{=IF(AND(A2=$A$2:$A$7<>A2,OR(AND(0<B2-$B$2:$B$7<>B2,B2-$B$2:$B$7<>B2<0.020833),B2-$B$2:$B$7<>B2=0,AND(-0.020833<B2-$B$2:$B$7<>B2,B2-$B$2:$B$7<>B2<0))),"TRUE","FALSE")}
```

```
=IF(AND(A3=A2,C3="TRUE"),"",A3)
```

the output of the C column is always false, is there a fix for the formula or another way of approaching this?

[image]

[image: what i want to happen]

Thank you ( sorry if this type of qn has already been answered  )

Comment: Please update your screenshot to include what result you are after exactly.

Comment: What should it show if there's 3 values for the same ID; the first and second differ 29 minutes, the third differs 11 from the second (40 from the first). What should the 3rd value read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a similar Excel sheet, containing two important things:

- The usage of the `TIME()` function, which makes it far more readable.
- The usage of `ABS()`: if you want to compare the size of a difference, never forget to take the absolute value :-)

The sheet contains some characters 'a' and 'b' with some time entries, the formula checks if the value equals 'a' and if the time is within 10 minutes of 8h45. The used formula is:

```
=AND(A3="a",ABS(B3-TIME(8,45,0)) <= TIME(0,10,0))
```

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

The colours are the result of conditional formatting, based on that same formula.

Comment: thank you for informing me about the time and abs functions

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with
`=IF(A2<>A1,"top no",IF(AND(A2<>A3,ABS(C2-C1)>TIME(0,30,0)),"bottom no",IF(AND(A2<>A3,ABS(C2-C1)<TIME(0,30,0)),"bottom yes",IF(ABS(C2-C1)>TIME(0,30,0),"mid no","mid yes"))))` and `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("*no*",K2)),"",A2)` to solve my problem